# subset data based on matching names in other data frame (R)

Tags: r, subset, correlation

In R, I want to automate removal of highly correlated variables so that I don't have to custom each code for each account. Right now I am making a table called `r` w/ correlations for all the variables I am testing and this step is fine:

```
r <- subset(r, r > 0.95)
```

I get:

```
row.names   r
max_stage10_    1.0000000
max_stage60_    0.9530657
ln_form_cnt7_   0.9509219
ln_form_cnt60_  0.9712263
```

These are the ones I want to remove.

These `row.names` match the names in another table, `ulmdata2`. How do I get `ulmdata2` data frame to remove variables that match the names that show up in the `r` table?

I can do it custom like this and it works, but would have to do it for every time and fill in the variables names:

```
ulmdata2 <- ulmdata2[,-which(names(ulmdata2) == "max_stage10_")] 
ulmdata2 <- ulmdata2[,-which(names(ulmdata2) == "max_stage60_")] 
ulmdata2 <- ulmdata2[,-which(names(ulmdata2) == "ln_form_cnt_7")] 
ulmdata2 <- ulmdata2[,-which(names(ulmdata2) == "ln_form_cnt_60")]
```

But the goal is to automate it so that if the name is in the  `r` table, I can remove it from the `ulmdata2` table quickly.

I played around with codes like this

```
ulmdata2 <- ulmdata2[,-which(ulmdata2$rownames == r$rownames)]
```

but it just deleted all of my `ulmdata2`. Other tweaks yielded no changes at all.

Comment: You can use `%in%` instead of `==` i.e. `ulmdata2[, !(names(ulmdata2) %in% c('max_stage10_', 'max_stage_60_', 'ln_form_cnt_7', 'ln_form_cnt_60'))]`  If it is the rownames of `r` then `ulmdata2[, !(names(ulmdata2) %in% r$row.names)]` assuming that row.names is a column in the r dataset.